# Jenkins set encoding utf8 not work in bat script

Tags: node.js, jenkins

i try to set jenkins encoding to utf-8, but it seems not work in some cases,here is my pipeline file:

```
def Notify(environment, type , content ){
    echo environment
    bat script: 'node D:\\JenkinsNotify\\notify.js '+ environment+'  '+ type +' '+ content+' '+ env.WORKSPACE
    
  
}
pipeline {
   agent {label 'master'}
   
    environment {
       
        LC_ALL = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANG    = 'en_US.UTF-8'
        LANGUAGE = 'en_US.UTF-8'
  
    }
    stages {
        
       stage('消息通知'){
            steps {
                echo 'notify'
            }
            post {
            
                success {
                    script{
                        Notify("开发测试环境",'text',"构建成功")
                    }
                }
                failure {
                  script{
                        Notify("开发测试环境",'text',"构建失败")
                    }
                }
            }
       }
        
    }
    
}
```

the output is not expected , the encoding is not correct :

```
D:\Jenkins\workspace\TestDemo>node D:\JenkinsNotify\notify.js 开发测试环�? text 构建成功 D:\Jenkins\workspace\TestDemo 
[
  'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
  'D:\\JenkinsNotify\\notify.js',
  '寮€鍙戞祴璇曠幆澧?',
  'text',
  '鏋勫缓鎴愬姛',
  'D:\\Jenkins\\workspace\\TestDemo'
]
测试中文能不能正常输入
```

[image]

the notify.js file :

```js
const arr = process.argv;

console.log(arr);
console.log('测试中文能不能正常输入');
```

i hava set jenkins startup params `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` in `jenkins.xml` , and set `LANG=zh_CN.UTF-8`, `LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8` in Jenkins System Configuration, but they are not work...

[image]
[image]

i have no idea to solve this problem, it take me many hours but still no answer

i have tried this way:

```
def NotifySuccess(environment){
    bat encoding:'UTF-8', script: 'node D:\\JenkinsNotify\\notify2.js 中文测试为什么不行 '+ environment+ env.WORKSPACE
    //bat script: 'node D:\\JenkinsNotify\\notify.js PDM_Backend_DevTest text true '+ env.WORKSPACE
}
```

and it still not work:

```
node D:\JenkinsNotify\notify2.js 中文测试为什么不�?测试中文输入是否可行D:\Jenkins\workspace\PDM_Backend_DevTest@2
```

### Environment

- Jenkins 2.414.1
- Windows Server 2022 21H2

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `encoding` [parameter](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-durable-task-step/#bat-windows-batch-script) in your `bat` step. Try adding `encoding: 'UTF-8'`

Comment: i have tried it and  not works too, so sad